# If a couple wishes to play in the same team, how many different teams can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

> A team of $4$ players consists of $2$ men and two women chosen from $3$ men and $4$ women. If a couple wishes to play in the same team, how many different teams can be formed?

The answer is $9$. However, I can only get six by
$(1C1)(1C1)(2C1)(3C1)$. How is the answer $9$?

Comment: A couple is supposed to be a man and a woman? Just making sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the cases where *neither* member of the couple are in the team are included – only those teams where one side of the couple is in and one is out are excluded.

The extra possibilities are then selected from a pool of $2$ men and $3$ women, hence $3$ more possible teams.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand where the three cases comes from?

Comment: Ahh I see (2C2) and (3C2) Thank you

Comment: @user71207 if our players are $ABC$ (men) and $DEFG$ (women) and our couple is $AD$, the teams not having $A$ or $D$ are $BCEF,BCFG,BCEG$. In fact, if the couple is not in, the men are fixed.